# How to Change Cloud API access scopes on GCP Compute Engine with out stopping the Instance

Tags: storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage, fuse, gcsfuse

I'm using `gcsfuse` inside Google Compute Engine. I mounted a folder with cloud storage bucket but, unable to create any file inside of it:

```
touch t1
```

with an error:

```
touch: cannot touch 't1': Input/output error
```

Solution for the issue is to give **Cloud API access scope: storage : read/write**

How to Change Cloud API access scopes on GCP Compute Engine with out stopping the Instance?
Please provide me the solution for this iisue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have insufficient GCS permissions. Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#credentials) for `gcsfuse`. If you're using a service account on a GCE VM make sure to set up the VM with the `storage-full` access scope.

You can try to fix it in this way:

1. create a service account (more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually))
2. create a key for the service account, and download the .json file
3. grant an appropriate role to the service account
4. grant the appropriate permissions to the service account on the bucket
5. upload the .json credentials for the service account to the VM
6. define an environment variable that contains the path to the service account credentials when calling `gcsfuse` from the command line:

   ```
   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = /root/credentials/service_credential_file.json gcsfuse bucket_name /my/mount/point
   ```

   use the `key_file` option to accomplish the same goal in `fstab` as it  documented [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#credentials).

In addition, you need to use the environment variable or `key_file` option even if you have configured the service account on the VM using:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /root/credentials/service_credential_file.json
```

Please update your question with your steps, commands and full outputs if you still have a problem.